# Win 7 & Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-7, authentication, workgroup

I have problem with Win 7 and Server 200. I can't access 2003, from Win 7. We can see the server from the network but can't access it. When I try it asks for the user name and password. I put in the correct username and password but I get an error massage stating `user name or password is invalid`. We are using a workgroup, not a domain.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the username/password combo that you are using on the windows 7 machine, windows 2003 machine, or both?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using "SERVERNAME\USERNAME" as the username?

For instance if your server is called SRV01 then try "SRV01\username" as the username.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone has changed your password.

Login any available computer which can allow you download. Insert a blank CD . Find Windows Password Key and download it, burn the iso image file to the cd. When finish, insert the disk to your computer, restart your computer, set the bios so that the computer boot from CD. Then you can clear your account password without knowing the current password.

Comment: Given that it would take about 2 seconds to check that the password is still valid, and another 2 to reset it if necessary, your idea seems extraordinary. Also looks kind of spammy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access a SMB share or remoting in via RDP?  I would try prefixing the username with the servername like mentioned above.  servername\username.  If its RDP, are you sure that the username you are trying to use has access to connect via RDP?

Are their any errors being generated on either box that you can view in the event viewer?

The last issue, is the time correct on the Windows 7 box?  I think that will cause problems with RDP and Shares.